# Security concerns about giving the apache user a tty

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, sudo

I need to invoke sudo from a PHP script (web-triggered) so as to run a command as another user.
However, I get the message "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo".

Would there be any security problem on giving the user `nobody` a tty??

Would you recommend a different approach to do what I need (run a shell script as a different user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm sudo requires tty?

```
visudo
```

Disable an option for a user (or the default setting):

```
!requiretty
```